# What's the normal flow for pigpiod.service?

Tags: pigpio, docker

I inherited a Python code from a former coworker that uses pigpio library to control Raspberry Pi pins. This code is running inside a Docker on the Raspberry Pi

I am now experiencing a problem in which, sometimes, when the Raspberry starts (and sequentially, that Docker), I'm getting the "Can't connect to pigpiod.service" error.

I noticed two things.

1.- Executing "sudo systemctl start pigpiod.service" solves the problem (And enabling it solves it for good)

2.- Sometimes, with the pigpiod.service inactive (and disabled), the code still runs fine, interacting with the pins and all.

I want to understand what's normal workflow between the library and the service so I can make sense of what's going on and be able to take into account when developing new stuff for RPi.

Thanks!

Comment: See `/lib/systemd/system/pigpiod.service`. You will need a systemd expert to answer your Question, but AFAIK there is no restart (and no need). NOTE the included service DOES NOT allow remote access; this needs to be explicitly started as it runs `/usr/bin/pigpiod -l`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only role of that service is to start (and stop) the pigpio daemon.  The Python module controls the GPIO by talking to the daemon.

The Python code will work if the pigpio daemon is running.  Presumably when it works without the service being run it means something else started the daemon or the daemon wasn't stopped by the service.

Personally I just start the daemon at boot using a crontab entry.  Some people prefer to use a service, some prefer to just start it manually as and when it's needed (sudo pigpiod).

Comment: Thanks! I thought the pigpiod.service WAS the daemon, so it didn't make sense in my head as to how it could be running when the service was inactive.

Quick question though, if the service is running and for whatever reason the daemon crashes, does the service restart the daemon or will it crash with the daemon?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know.  I wrote the daemon but had nothing to do with the service and do not understand how it works.